# Configure XADisk as JCA Resource Adapter on Websphere

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, jca, xadisk

I've deployed XADisk.rar (1.2.2) on my Websphere JCA Resource Adapter list.

Now I'm trying to configure it using the tab "Custom properties". Some properties are easily editable (like the instanceId), but some others are not (like xaDiskHome - which is a quite important one).

Why and how to make these properties editable?

Comment: Its hard to tell from description, what you have done already, but some properties are editable for the connection. So maybe try to create connection factory for your adapter and see if you will be able to edit these properties on the connection factory level.

Comment: At the connection factory level, I can't do much things. The only property that shows up is the "instanceId". Others are simply not displayed, and I can't add anything.

Comment: Ok, this is extremely funny bug. I assume you have installed RAR in traditional WAS, and you are trying to edit it via admin console > Resource adapters, and your xaDiskHome property is on the `second` page of props list. Above the list there is button to change list size from 20 to something bigger eg. 100. If that property is on the first page, it IS editable :-))) I've tested it on WAS 8.5.5.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly like you're saying. By default on the 2nd page, and I can change the page size on the "Preferences". Except that... xaDiskHome is NEVER editable, making the list on 1 or 2 or more pages doesn't do anything. I run WAS 8.5.5.9, one as Network Deployment installation, and one as a standalone one. xaDiskHome is never editable...

Comment: Hooo wait... After playing a bit with the filter (Maximum rows), now it IS editable.... Don't understand completely what's going on... But I will continue to investigate...

Comment: Ok, cool. Try to edit/save some other properties. In my case, the ones on the second page were not editable :-). But in general, if you have support and time you should create PMR ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108821/discussion-between-gas-and-spi).

Comment: A PMR is actually in progress :-) but I created a SO topic before, just in case this was a well known issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments by Gas, there is a bug in the WebSphere frontend console, that make any entry on the 2nd or more page of the "Custom properties" page READ ONLY.

Changing the filter value to display "100" entries per page, and playing a bit with the UI, I was able to configure XA Disk fully. Funny bug yea, but it costed me much much time to find the cause...